# Android: How to hide text being entered in Edit Text box?

Tags: android, android-edittext, passwords

How can I ensure that text being entered in an Edit Text box is not shown to the user entering it?
I.e. when entering a password etc?

**Activity code:**

```
            ePass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.euPass);


                    String password = ePass.getText().toString();
```

**XML:**

```
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/euPass"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_bottom_bg"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/password"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:password="true"
            android:textColorHint="#bbbbbb" />
```

Answer (score 3):

For passwords, Programmatically you should use

```
epass.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

And in your layout use

```
android:password="true"
```

Please note that According to the [TextView documents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html), the programmatic version of `android:password` is `setTransformationMethod()`, not `setInputType()`.

Comment: looks a complete and short answer...rated up

Comment: Thanks, however this is still showing the letter being entered before it blanks it out, how can i get that it is just blank entries each time

Comment: I don't think something like that is possible.So if this answer solved your problem please accept it as a correct answer.If it helped you upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

for passwords use:

```
 android:inputType="textPassword"
```

so your xml should have:

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/euPass"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_bottom_bg"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/password"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:password="true"
            android:textColorHint="#bbbbbb" 
            android:inputType="textPassword"/>
```